# How to print crossed words using a for loop?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get two words to print out crossed at their common letter. I have gotten the second word to print out vertically but my first word won't print out where it is supposed to cross with the second word.

It prints as so:

> ```
> lotteryb
> lotteryo
> lotterya
> lotteryt
> lotteryb
> lotteryo
> lotterya
> lotteryt
> lotteryb
> lotteryo
> lotterya
> lotteryt
> ```

This is what it is supposed to look like:

```
 b
lottery
 a
 t

  b
  o
  a
lottery

   b
   o
   a
lottery
```

Here is my code, any help would be great!

```
public class Assg2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

            String w1 = args[0];
            String w2 = args[1];

            int numberOfCrosses = 0;




            for(int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++)
            {       
                for(int j=0; j < w2.length(); j++)
                {


                    if(w1.charAt(i) == w2.charAt(j))
                    {
                        numberOfCrosses++;

                        for( char ch : w2.toCharArray())
                        {
                        System.out.print(w1);
                        System.out.println(ch);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        if(numberOfCrosses == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Words do not cross ");
        }


    }


    private static boolean crossesAt(String w1, int pos1, String w2, int pos2)
    {
        for( pos1 = 0; pos1 < w1.length(); pos1++)
        {
            for( pos2 = 0; pos2 < w2.length(); pos2++)
            {
                if(w1.charAt(pos1) == w2.charAt(pos2))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    return true; }



}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of input and **expected output**? It would help understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the first word and the character in the second word as soon as you find a matching character. Try the following

```
public class Assg2{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String w1 = args[0];
        String w2 = args[1];

        int numberOfCrosses = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < w2.length(); j++)
            {
                if(w1.charAt(i) == w2.charAt(j))
                {
                    numberOfCrosses++;
                    printWords(w1,w2,i,j);
                }
            }
        }
        if(numberOfCrosses == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Words do not cross ");
        }
   }

    private static void printWords(String w1, String w2, int index1, int index2) {
        for(int i=0;i<index2;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<index1;j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(w2.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println(w1);
        for(int i=index2+1;i<w2.length();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<index1;j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(w2.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```